# How to send a request to a servlet from a scriptlet in a JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, scriptlet

Kind of a simple question, but it has me stuck. I want execute a servlet from within a JSP, so I tried something like the following:

```
<%
    //Fetch server name port from request
    //Fetch email_addr from DB request
                   *
                   *
                   *
    //Forward request to servlet sendWelcomeMsg
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/sendWelcomeMsg?  
      recipient=" + email_addr + 
      "&contentServerName=" + request.getServerName() + 
      "&contentServerPort=" + request.getServerPort());
    rd.forward(request, response);
%>
```

The above kind of works, in that if I manually refresh the page, the rest of the page gets rendered, but only if I do the refresh. So, my questions are,

1. Is there a better way to do this without a major rewrite of my JSP?
2. Failing 1., how can I refresh the page programmatically from within the scriptlet?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a form to the page that lets the user invoke the servlet at will (the servlet sends a Welcome message and the user may want to send several, as a test).

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding from JSP to Servlet is not normal. It's supposed to be the other way round. Otherwise, the servlet is entirely taking over the response processing. You might see `IllegalStateException` errors in the servet log when it's JSP's turn.

You can however include a servlet's output in JSP (note that the servlet in question can and should not modify the response headers):

```
rd.include(request, response);
```

Still, that's not the normal practice. If you intend to perform a business task on a GET request before presenting the results in a JSP, then you need to put that task in servlet's `doGet()` and let it forward to the JSP.  The request should hit the controller first, which is usually a servlet, which in turn forwards to the view, which is usually a JSP. You can find an example in [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).